# Multiple conversation Neoload

Tags: performance-testing

I am doing performance-testing using Neoload, i am new to Neoload, i have recorded a scenario where there will be login page after login, perform search, after loading search results, select one record and update data and submit.

Step1. Login to application which will load the home page

step2. Select the search link and provide the criteria, there search result will be displayed

Step3. From search result select one record (based on Id) data will be displayed on the other page.

Step 4. modify the data rendered by step3 and submit the page.

In the above scenario, what i am doing is trying to pass dynamic content (passing multiple Ids) in step 3 to generate the load, here i am not able to understand why neoload is not able continue take the response and pass it to next request, this is how the scenario has been recorded

Your help appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to select a record based on Id and then modify the data rendered when click the id and then click submit.
The only thing that changes here on every request is the Id.

For that please follow the steps mentioned below,

1. I suppose you don't want to login/logout on every request but want to change the Id selected on every request. For that place the login and logout script in the init and end placeholders respectively.
2. Go to Edit->Variables.
3. Click on the function icon "fx" in the bottom and choose you desired data type and create a variable 'xyz'.
4. Provide the min and max values and make sure to select "Value Change Policy" to "on each iteration".
5. Now go to the script where you had clicked on Id in the Search Box.
6. Once you find the Id, you'll have to replace it with a dynamic value as ${xyz}.